# e.root is undefined in all.js

Tags: javascript, facebook

Anyone know why I might be getting the following error:

```
e.root is undefined in all.js
```

Not really sure what I have wrong here. Here is the relavent portion of my code..

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
  channelURL : 'https://nowfoods.marketspacecom.com/channel.html', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});

// Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
  }(document));

</script>

</head>
<body>

<a href="javascript:fb_publish();" class="fbshare"><img src="images/share.gif" /></a>

<script type="text/javascript">

//set the height of the canvas
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.Canvas.setSize({height: 1250});
}


//this function will publish a post to the user's wall
function fb_publish() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      name: 'Get a free sample of <?php echo $getLatestPromoID['prodName']; ?> from NOW Foods!',
    link: '<?php echo $fbconfig['appBaseUrl']; ?>',
 picture: 'https://nowfoods.marketspacecom.com/images/nowicon.gif',
 caption: 'NOW Foods Free Samples',
 description: 'I just signed up for a free sample of NOW Foods <?php echo $getLatestPromoID['prodName']; ?>. You can get one too at the link above!'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }

</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

</body>
```

XXX X X X XX X XX X XXXXX X XXXX X XXX

XXX X X X XX X XX X XXXXX X XXXX X XXX

XXX X X X XX X XX X XXXXX X XXXX X XXX

XXX X X X XX X XX X XXXXX X XXXX X XXX

XXX X X X XX X XX X XXXXX X XXXX X XXX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "`<div id="fb-root"></div>`" must come before the script include I think...